# background image overlays text

Tags: p5.js

I'm new to p5play and was trying to make a flappy bird game. Everything works fine, but none of my texts display. When I tried commenting out code where I deal with the background image, the texts showed up so I guess the background image just lays on top of the text and covers up all the texts.

I tried adding the texts after I'm putting the background on, but since I am using camera to track my flappy bird and make the background move along I'm a little confused as to where I'm supposed to add the texts so that they show up.

Here's my setup() and draw() function with minimum extra code (I have comments of what the code is doing but have removed the actual code that is unrelated to make it simpler):

```
function setup() {
  
    // allSprites.debug=kb.presses('w')
    createCanvas(400, 600);
    
    //Create sky & ground sprite
    sky=new Sprite(skybg);
    sky.collider='n';
    ground = new Sprite(groundImg,200, 350, 750, 40, "n");
    groundImg.resize(1500,0);

    //Set the camera location
    camera.x = 150;
    gameOver = true;
    canStartNewGame = true;
}
```

```
function draw() {


    allSprites.debug=kb.pressing('w')
    //Starts the game with a mouse pressed or space bar
    if (mouse.presses() || kb.presses("space")) {
        bird.vel.y = -9;
    
        if (canStartNewGame) {
          newGame();
        }
    }

    //If the game isn't over run the code
    if (!gameOver) {

    //Create new pipes every 60 frames (1 second)

    //Get rid of pipes when they reach the left side of screen

    //remove points when bird eats it
    
    
        //Wrap ground 
        if (camera.x > ground.x + width / 2) {
            ground.x += width;
            sky.x +=width
        }
        
    }

  //The camera follows the bird's x axis movement
    camera.x = bird.x + 150;
    
    // Adjust the position of the sky based on the camera's position
    let skyX = skybg.width / 2 - camera.x * 0.2;
    image(skybg, skyX, 0);

    camera.on();

    if (!gameOver) {
          camera.x = bird.x + 150;
          world.step();
    }
    text("score : " + score, bird.x, bird.y);

}
```

The text that I am trying to add is : `text("score : " + score, bird.x, bird.y);` on the last line of `function draw()`

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? If there are none, please include your full code, e.g., where is the variable `score` defined, etc. A p5js editor link would be ideal to help us identify the problems in your code.

Comment: @kikon I've added replit link which is where im working

Comment: So, in the replit the score does show up, and is updated on screen when increased. What is not happening from what you're expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to run the code that you posted. Have you considered using `createDiv()`?

```js
let txt;

function setup() {
 createCanvas(400, 400);
 txt = createDiv('');
 txt.style('font-size', '16px');
 txt.position(30, 60);
}

function draw() {
  if (frameCount % 100 == 0){
    txt.html('score: '+str(int(random(255))));
    background(random(255,100));  
  }  
}
```

Comment: How can I remove the text completely if I'm trying to go into some other screen like Home screen, or how to play screen?

Comment: Try txt.remove();

Comment: I'm unable to use the text again if I do txt.remove(). I want my game over text to show up after every loss, but once I do txt.remove(), it never shows up again.

Comment: Try txt.html(''); when you don't want to see the score message.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer shouldn't be accepted, sorry. Creating a div is not the easiest way to display text in p5play.

If you want the text to be right above the bird sprite, simply set `bird.text` to the desired text.

But if not, your sprites are covering the text. p5play automatically draws sprites at the end of the draw loop. Use the p5.js `text` function before drawing a sprite manually with `sprite.draw()` or every sprite with `allSprites.draw()`.